# List node comments using existing comment.tpl.php from custom Drupal module

Tags: comments, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a module which gets the comments from the nodes which the user has specified as 'favourites'. So I'm not trying to output all comments from all nodes like the recent comments block do, but just the ones from nodes specified as 'favourites'.

The queries all work, I've tested this by printing values from the different objects. So I've got the whole comment object for each comment and the corresponding node object. I've been able to create lists of the cid, nid, comment text etc. and output these with

```
$block['content'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

but how would I go about rendering the comment objects I've got in my module in the same layout/design as I have on my node pages? The comments on my node pages are rendered with the comment.tpl.php file which I set up with my own layout/design and I'd like my module to render these comments the same way.

So this is my hook_block_view() implementation which I believe is the correct way for output from a module:

```
function jf_comment_feed_block_view($delta = '') {
switch($delta){
    case 'jf_comment_feed':
        $block['subject'] = t('Comment feed');
        if(user_access('access content')){
            // Get users favourite locations
            $loc_result = jf_comment_feed_locations();

            $fav_loc = array();
            foreach ($loc_result as $loc) {
                $fav_loc[] = array(
                    'data' => $loc->nid,
                );
            }

            if (empty($fav_loc)) { //No content in the last week.
                $block['content'] = t('No favourite locations added.
                    To see what goes on at your favourite locations add locations to 
                    +My Locations and the posts from those locations will show here.');  
            } else {
                //Use our custom function to retrieve data.
                $result = jf_comment_feed_contents($fav_loc);

                // ############################################
                // Here I need to create my output... I think...

                // Previously I rendered my results from the query
                // by using this code (this prints the comment id):
                // $items = array();
                // foreach ($result as $comment){
                //   $items[] = array(
                //     'data' => comment_load($comment->cid),
                //   );
                // }
                // ############################################

                if (empty($items)) { //No content in the last week.
                    $block['content'] = t('No posts from last week.');  
                } else {
                    // This is the code used to render the 
                    // comment id to the block: 
                    // $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
                }
            }
        }
}
return $block;
}
```

I've also tried with:

```
$block['content'] = theme('comment_view', $mycomment, $mynode);
$block['content'] = theme('comment', $mycomment, $mynode);
```

where $mycomment is the comment object and $mynode is the node object. But this breaks the page.

Surely there must be a line of code I'm missing here, but I've now spent two days googling this and had no luck... So thanks for any help with this.

**EDIT**
@Clive did trigger some ideas and I tried creating my own array based on what the arrays look like on the node page. I got the structure and names for the array with the Devel Themer info module.

This array outputs the comments creators user pic and the date, but I've added a custom field, field_jf_comment, to my comments and this isn't showing, although I can see the information in the array with Devel. I don't use the standard out-of-the-box comment field because I wanted a textfield and not a scalable textarea for the input. A design decision.

Now obviously this isn't ideal as I set most of the values manually. This works for my current project, but would be cool if the module was a bit more generic so other people could use it too. When I click on a individual comment on my node page with Devel Themer info I get an array which has elements, the user object and array items such as db_is_active, is_admin among other things. If I could somehow recreate this array and then set this array to $block['content'] I believe this would work.

Here's the implementation of the array:

```
foreach ($result as $comment) {
  $items[] = array(
    '#entity_type' => 'comment',
    '#bundle' => 'comment_node_location',
    '#theme' => 'comment__node_location',
    '#comment' => comment_load($comment->cid, FALSE),
    '#node' => node_load($comment->nid),
    '#view_mode' => 'full',
    'field_jf_comment' => array(
      '#theme' => 'field',
      '#title' => 'Title',
      '#access' => TRUE,
      '#label_display' => 'above',
      '#view_mode' => 'full',
      '#language' => 'und',
      '#field_name' => 'field_jf_comment',
      '#field_type' => 'text',
      '#entity_type' => 'comment',
      '#bundle' => 'comment_node_location',
      '#items' => array(
        '0' => array(
          // This isn't working and gives an error saying:
          // Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_jf_comment in
          // jf_comment_feed_block_view()
          'value' => $comment->field_jf_comment['und']['0']['value'],
          'format' => $comment->field_jf_comment['und']['0']['format'],
          'safe_value' => $comment->field_jf_comment['und']['0']['safe_value']
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

And I get it rendered with:

```
$block['content'] = $items;
```

**EDIT**
@Clive was right. His code does the same as mine, but in way less code. And with some modifications I managed to get my custom field in there too:

```
$content = '';
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $single_comment = comment_load($item['cid']);
  $custom_field = field_attach_view('comment', $single_comment, 'field_jf_comment');
  $to_render = array(
    '#theme' => 'comment',
    '#comment' => $single_comment,
    '#node' => node_load($item['nid']),
    'field_jf_comment' => $custom_field
    );

  $content .= render($to_render);
}

$block['content'] = $content;
```

Now the only thing I'm missing is the links for each comment. The only one I'm using is the Reply to comment. Anyone got any idea of how to get that to show too?

Answer (score 0):

The `theme()` calls probably break because you're using Drupal 7 but trying to pass the parameters in a Drupal 6 style. If you have a look at the [`theme_comment()` documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_comment/7) you can see it takes a single `$variables` parameter which should be an array. Try this:

```
$content = '';
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $to_render = array(
    '#theme' => 'comment',
    '#comment' => comment_load($item['cid'])
  );

  $content .= render($to_render);
}

$block['content'] = $content;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it out, but unfortunately it's not working. If I do it exactly as you suggest it breaks the whole page and gives me these errors:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: bottom in include() (line 85 of ../all/themes/zen/templates/maintenance-page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: #comment in template_preprocess_comment() (line 2263 of ../modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in template_preprocess_comment() (line 2264 of ../modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_comment() (line 2268 of ../comment/comment.module).
Warning: date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date() (line 1909 of ../includes/common.inc).

Comment: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date() (line 1919 of ../includes/common.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_comment() (line 2269 of ../modules/comment/comment.module).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type comment. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7409 of ../includes/common.inc).

Comment: @user1129660: Sorry about that the code I posted was wrong, I've edited it could you try that?

Comment: Yes if I add '#node' => node_load($item['nid']) into the $to_render array I get the comments, but my custom field is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

The new Drupal 7 `theme()` syntax takes an array for its second argument. This array will be extracted before calling the template file so each key will become a new php var.

For example `array( 'comment' => $mycomment )` will get you a `$comment`variable in your template.

Hope this can help.